# How would you compare/choose between the Hash/BTree option available with Berkeley DBs

Tags: berkeley-db

How would you compare/choose between the Hash/BTree option available with Berkeley DBs

-Ajay

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at this question/answer as well [about Hash VS B-Tree](http://bit.ly/ebLsjQ)

Regards,

Dave